# R package Rmpfr

Tags: r

I am trying to install [Rmpfr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/index.html) in a Ubuntu machine. But I kept getting the following error.

```
configure: error: Header file mpfr.h not found; maybe use --with-mpfr-include=INCLUDE_PATH
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Rmpfr’
```

Could anyone help me with this, please? Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need `mpfr.h` which you get from

```
sudo apt-get install libmpfr-dev
```

This recipe is generic: you need the (Linux) `-dev` package for compilation against a (Linux) library which is what the (R) package does here.