# Troubles with shiny markdown and Rmpfr (0.5-7) package

Tags: r, shiny, markdown, rstudio

I am using RStudio on a windows machine. recently, I wanted to deploy an shiny-markdown document using the `HH` library - wihout sucess. I broke down the error to the following test program

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r}
require( Rmpfr )
```
````

This program works well if I run it locally. However, if I try to deploy it to shinyapps.io using `shinyapps::deployApp()`, RStudio tries to build the package `Rmpfr` from source even tough the package is already installed. This building from source fails with the following error (full error log: http://pastebin.com/D5KVc44n)

```
configure: error: Header file mpfr.h not found; maybe use --with-mpfr-include=INCLUDE_PATH
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Rmpfr’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rmpfr’
################################# End Task Log ################################# 
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 61322212 failed: Error building image: Error building Rmpfr (0.5-7). Build exited with non-zero status: 1
```

---

I think this question is related to [this one about the rmpfr package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31311050/r-package-rmpfr), but the solution does not work on windows since it uses the `apt-get` command.

Any suggestions are welcome.

---

**EDIT**: I already tried to make `mpfr.h` available. I downloaded the `mpfr` package from http://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/, unpacked it and added it to the windows PATH variable. I also copied the entries of the mpfr-3.0.0 folder to the R working directory. Both methods showed no success.

Comment: RStudio is not building from source on your own machine -- what you're seeing is output from a machine on shinyapps.io that's getting ready to host your document. That's the machine missing mpfr.h, and unfortunately there's no easy way to get the file onto the machine. You might try posting this to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/shinyapps-users.

Comment: Thank you so much! I assumed it was a problem with my machine since a similar deployment worked one year ago on a linux machine. I will keep this question updated with the responses from my question on google groups https://groups.google.com/d/msg/shinyapps-users/et7cwiZrhRQ/bjTKm5HZGwAJ