# Where to deploy R project in local shiny server

Tags: r, shiny-server

I need a help,
I have installed shiny server and rstudio in my local Virtual Machine(VM), then i can able to access from browser, now i want to deploy R project into shiny server.

but i'm not able get that, where to deploy.
in tomcat we have webapp folder, which folder is in the shiny server.
Any one please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to save your ui.R and server.R on the shiny server here:

/srv/shiny-server/folder_with_your_apps/app_name

see (http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#deploying-applications) section 7.1.1

Then you just add the above path onto your host site name:

http://your.host.site:port_name/folder_with_your_apps/app_name

The default port for shiny server is 3838 but you can change that.

Your error on shinyapps.io is a different matter.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, i got it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with own shiny server but this may help you get started if you are not used to Shiny.

In RStudio, you can deploy using this button in the GUI as long as you are in the `ui.R` and `server.R` files.

[image: deployappicon in RStudio]

1. Copy a basic example from their Shiny tutorial - http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/.
2. Open file and then look for this button and click deploy

   You can use RunApp just to get it working okay locally.
3. Look at the settings to see if you can link it to your server. (I go straight to `shinyapps.io`, but see if this helps you work out how to set locally.)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, when i publishing into shinyapps.io i'm getting this error

checking mpfr.h usability... no 
checking mpfr.h presence... no 
checking for mpfr.h... no 
configure: error: Header file mpfr.h not found; maybe use --with-mpfr-include=INCLUDE_PATH 
ERROR: configuration failed for package �Rmpfr� 
* removing �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rmpfr�
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 179985799 failed: Error building image: Error building Rmpfr (0.6-0). Build exited with non-zero status: 1 
Execution halted

Comment: Never seen that before. Have you looked at these answers for clues? [R package Rmpfr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31311050/r-package-rmpfr) and [Troubles with shiny markdown and Rmpfr 0.5-7 package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746513/troubles-with-shiny-markdown-and-rmpfr-0-5-7-package). Seems there is trouble with this Rmpfr. Please also take a look at http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/shinyapps.html to make sure you have the `rsconnect` right, using packages on github and look at comments at bottom of that page for help.